# How to add condition between two fields while using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, drupal

Updated Question :

I have two fields in the registration form Iam & you_are. First field contains A,B,C,D & Second field contains same A,B,C,D. I want to add Jquery through which if I select A or B then in second field only show B & C. It mean that if I select A or B then from second field A & B both are gone to hidden mode. Please Help. Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("$i_am=='A' || $i_am=='B'").select(function(){

     //condition here

    }
```

$i_am & $you_are are the drupal variable or the field variable

Comment: Please add some code to your post, by using the edit link underneath your post.

Comment: Please help @reporter

Comment: Have you select html element for selection?

Comment: $i_am & $you_are are the drupal field variable

Comment: @veera what are 'drupal' fields? Did you mean the php cms 'Drupal'? The webbrwoser cannot deal with drupal fields, only with HTML elements. So what type of fields are 'i_am' and 'you_are' (take a look at the source code in your browser)?

Comment: if field are edit-field-iam & edit-field-youare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple ways of doing this. I had a similar task to carry out few days back. What approach I came was the following:

- I checked for the selected value.
- I then had few arrays with values that I need to populate on the screen based on condition.
- Then I created my HTML myself in the div(s).

Code:

```
function CreateFormFields(control) {
    $("#dynamicFieldsPanel").empty();
    $("#normalDynamicFields").empty();

    var selectedSurvey = control.options[control.selectedIndex].text; // The control on whose value I had to create dynamic fields.

    var defaultLabels = ['Client Reference Number',
       'Request Date',
       'Survey Date',
       'Survey Time'];

    var labelsIfMandoobOrCPV = ['Company Name',
       'Contact Person Name',
       'Contact Number',
       'City Client',
       'Street Name',
       'Building Name Client'];

    var labelsIfAuto = ['Dealer Name (Seller)',
       'Dealer Name (Buyer)',
       'Street Name',
       'Building Name',
       'Contact Number',
       'Chassis Number',
       'Car Make',
       'Car Model'];

defaultLabels.forEach(function (value) {
    if (value.indexOf('Reference') !== -1) {
        $("#normalDynamicFields").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '" type="text" class="fields" /></li>');
    }
    else if (value.indexOf('Number') !== -1) {
        $("#normalDynamicFields").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '" type="text" class="fields" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" MaxLength="11" /></li>');
    }
    else {
        $("#normalDynamicFields").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '" type="text" class="fields" /></li>');
    }
});

if (selectedSurvey == "CPV" || selectedSurvey == "Mandoob") {
    labelsIfMandoobOrCPV.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value.indexOf('Number') !== -1) {
            $("#dynamicFieldsPanel").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '" type="text" class="fields" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" MaxLength="11" /></li>');
        }
        else if (value.indexOf('Reference') !== -1) {
            $("#dynamicFieldsPanel").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '" type="text" class="fields" /></li>');
        }
        else {
            $("#dynamicFieldsPanel").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '') + '" type="text" class="fields" /></li>');
        }
    });
}
else if (selectedSurvey == "Auto") {
    labelsIfAuto.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value.indexOf('Number') !== -1) {
            $("#dynamicFieldsPanel").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace("(", "").replace(")", "") + '" type="text" class="fields" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" MaxLength="11" /></li>');
        }
        else {
            $("#dynamicFieldsPanel").append('<li><p class="label">' + value + '</p><input id="txt' + value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace("(", "").replace(")", "") + '" type="text" class="fields" /></li>');
        }
    });
}

    AttachPluginsToControls();
}
```

Now you'll have to give this code sometime to understand. But it will suffice you, if I understood correctly your requirements.

Comment: I had to put some validations and other things on the dynamic fields, therefore I have done checks like:
`if (value.indexOf('Number') !== -1)`

This means the textbox will have numbers only. So I add:
`onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"` Which is another function that ensures only numbers get inserted.